# MATLAB GUI doesn't run report function properly

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-deployment

I have designed a GUI using the guide toolbox in MATLAB. Basically what this GUI does is that after clicking the 'Start' button, it will run a script that generates reports.

I used Report Generator toolbox to configure the reports, so in the script the code would be like:

```
report(buildBiweeklyReport);
```

where 'buildBiweeklyReport' contains a template consists of a title, a table, and some images and figures.

But after I compiled the GUI and clicked the 'Start' button, there were no images or figures in all the reports generated. The title and the table were included perfectly, though.

More specifically, there are two different 'sources' of images in my report template. One is opened from a .png file, the other is generated by a plot function, then included in the report by 'Figure Snapshot'.

Here is what I've tried:

1. By running the script in MATLAB, I can get the reports with all images.
2. By running the GUI script in MATLAB, then clicking the 'Start' button, I can get the reports with all images.
3. By running the .exe I've compiled, the reports WON'T have the images.

Comment: It is kind of hard to comment with no code or any more detailed explanation. Did you check if there are any errors in your code that are suppressed when compiled? As in [running it from the command line](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/126115-standalone-gui-to-exe), which would get you some info on that.

Answer (score 0):

I would check to be sure that the images are on the path *of the executable*. The path may not be same as the path when you execute your command at the command line. Add a line in the code to display the current directory that the executable is using (`disp('pwd')`).